# how do you comment on RFC?

Tags: rfc

is there general guideline about writing comment on RFC?

Comment: I think it would depend on the RFC. See similar question, [How do you comment on an RFC?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2586111/how-do-you-comment-on-an-rfc), but the author was specifically asking about OAuth. Also see this related question: [What is RFC?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/153735/what-is-rfc).

Comment: You use the transmission protocol detailed in RFC 1149, http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1149.html

Answer (score 2):

According to the [IETF](http://www.ietf.org/rfc.html), once published, an RFC does not change.  Errata can be submitted to the [editor at rfc-editor.org](http://www.rfc-editor.org/errata.php).  Comments on unpublished RFCs can be submitted to the relevant [IETF working groups](http://datatracker.ietf.org/wg/) or to the author(s) directly.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.rfc-editor.org/styleguide.html

Comment: Please try to avoid posting plain links to outside resources, with no added value.